# Possible to convert RSA private+public key to .pfx file?

Tags: .net, cryptography

I've got an RSA (XML) private+public key. Is there any way to create a .pfx file from this?

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged .NET I'll assume you're looking for an API do to this...

The assembly [`Mono.Security.dll`](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security), that ships with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) but works well with MS.NET on Windows, has a [`PKCS12`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.X509/PKCS12.cs) type that allows you to create .pfx files (with or without an X.509 certificate).

Note that it's a low-level API, used by the mono [tools](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/tools/security), but it might be a bit more complex than other API. OTOH since mono tools are built using this you can copy-paste the source code that does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the commandline tool [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/) to convert certificatats.

Try

```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -out newCertificate.pfx -inkey myKey.pem -in myCertificate.cer -name "myCertificateName@myDomain.net"
```